# pandas change datetime data to day

Tags: pandas, datetime

[image]

`new_surveys2["time"]`

I have this code, 
and I am trying to convert this datetime data to day

for example, the first column is **887    09:14:16.752474**

I like to convert this column to 0.384907 day.

I have no idea how to convert this.
should i just calculate each day, minute, second to day 
and just add all of them?

I like to see your answers thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will work with your example

```py
from datetime import timedelta

df['float_days'] = df['time'].dt.seconds / timedelta(days=1).total_seconds()
```